# C++ Class with many methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns, refactoring, anti-patterns

I am designing a distributed file system, one of the core classes is the FileSystem class which looks like:

```
class FileSystem {
public:
  exists(Path*);
  insert_file(File*);
  insert_block(Block*);
  remove(Path*);
  list();
  update_file(File*);
  update_block(Block*);
  get_file(Path*);
  get_block(Block*);
  move(Path*, Path*);
  copy(Path*, Path*);
  ...
  ... // More and more methods
};
```

I succeeded refactoring the project, however, I can not refactor this class, whenever I need to add a behavior (decorator or sub-typing) I ended up making more complex my design. Another problem is the amount of dependencies of this class (Path, block, file among others not included in the snippet).

The main cause is that this FS class has too many responsibilities, but still I can not find a way to split this File system class into different classes. I wonder if there is any pattern for this kind of situation, if not, how would you deal with this giant class?

Comment: First job. Introduce some `const` correctness. For once, `Java` (IMHO), didn't make a complete pig's ear of their `File` and `Path` objects. Why not look at those for inspiration? Or maybe just use the file system classes from Boost and spend all the time you save outside in the sunshine.

Comment: The code snippet is  C++ like pseudo-code, the question concerns the architecture of the classes rather the `const` correctness (I fail to see how describing which method does or does not alter the object's state is related to this question).

Comment: Thats a good idea but my the FS I am implementing is slightly different since its distributed. However the interfaces would be similar. I'll have a look

Comment: I had a quick look to the Java FS API, it's actually a great inspiration, maybe delegating the file operations to the file class seems to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [C++ Core Guideline C.4](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c4-make-a-function-a-member-only-if-it-needs-direct-access-to-the-representation-of-a-class):

> Make a function a member only if it needs direct access to the representation of a class

In the above example it is not clear what internal state Filesystem has, but I guess minimal. Any function that can be expressed by its public interface should a free function. Another way of saying is that any function that is not involved in keeping the class invariant should not be part of the interface.

I guess file system is represented only by its current folder.

```cpp
class FileSystem {
  private:
    Path* directory_;
  public:
    FileSystem(Path *directory) : directory_ {directory};
    Path* directory() { return directory_; };
};
```

An example of a member function that maintains an invariant would be `chdir`. If that is even of interest. It could as well be a free function that returns a new FileSystem, making the class basically immutable, which is very desirable, see [Guideline Con.1](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#con1-by-default-make-objects-immutable).

```cpp
class FileSystem {
...
    chdir(Path* subpath) { /* checks */ ... }
};
```

All the other above function can be expressed by the public interface, so they should be non-member functions:

```cpp
exists(FileSystem*, Path*);
insert_file(FileSystem*, File*);
insert_block(FileSystem*, Block*);
remove(FileSystem*, Path*);
list(FileSystem*);
update_file(FileSystem*, File*);
update_block(FileSystem*, Block*);
get_file(FileSystem*, Path*);
get_block(FileSystem*, Block*);
move(FileSystem*, Path*, Path*);
copy(FileSystem*, Path*, Path*);
```